# JQuery: How to disable form from submission when default values aren't changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How do I go about disabling the form from submission if the default username and password values are not changed or left blank? I want also to show an alert message if nothing is changed or filled out. Here's my code:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type=text], input[type=password]').focus(function() {

            if(this.value === this.defaultValue)
            {
                 $(this).val("");
            }
        }).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
            }
        });
    })
</script>

<form id=""form1" action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="un" value="Username"/>
<input type="password" name="pw" value="Password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out implementing the [jQuery Validate Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate).

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/wXWnZ/).

```
<body>

.... other content ....

<form id="form1" action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="un" placeholder="Username" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Password" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#form1').validate({
        errorElement: 'label',
        rules: {
            un: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
            },
            pw: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            un: {
                required: 'Please enter your name.'
            },
            pw: {
                required: 'Please enter your password.',
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly on Chrome but not on IE8 which I need to get it work on since our company computers use IE8 mostly...

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin (if that's what you're talking about) works fine in IE

Comment: Right. For some reason it doesn't work on my IE8. Maybe because of HTML5 form parameters. It still submits form with default values.

Comment: Are you including the validate plugin (not just the code above) on the page? Check my answer - I added it for you.

Comment: That work at this time. I must have put the script in the <head> section. Thanks! I just have a little issue. The "placeholder" parameter doesn't work on IE8 so I tried to change it to "value" and validation doesn't seem to work. Is there anything can be done about that?

Comment: If my solution worked for you, please mark it as correct :)

 - The `placeholder` attribute is not supported in IE8. Your only easy alternatives are to use a `<label>` for the field, or implement a placeholder replacement script, like this one: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

change html to:

```
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();"/>
```

function validate form:

```
function validateForm(){
    var defaultValue ='blabla';
    var text = $('input[type=text]').val();
    var pass= $('input[type=password]').val();
    if(text.length==0||text===defaultValue||pass.length==0||pass===defaultValue){
       return false;
       //alert if you want
    }
    else{
       return true;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's work..

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="un" default="Username" value="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="pw" default="Password" value="Password"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm()"/>
</form>

<script>

function validateForm(){
            if($('input[type=text], input[type=password]').val()!=$('input[type=text], input[type=password]').attr("default")){
                $("#form1").submit();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

$(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type=text], input[type=password]').focus(function() {

            if($(this).val() === $(this).attr("default"))
            {
                 $(this).val("");
            }
        }).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).val($(this).attr("default"));
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... It alerts when submit button is clicked, but form still submits though default values are not changed...

Comment: it's work if you channge the `validateForm` function.. so i'm change it, and it's work..

`if($("#exampleinput").val()!==$("#exampleinput").attr("default"))` then form submit

Answer (score 0):

There you go ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PMqF/)), note usage of ids on inputs:

```
<form id="form1" action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="un" name="un" value="Username"/>
    <input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" value="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

With pure JS:

```
var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
form1.onsubmit = function() {
    var un = document.getElementById("un");
    var pw = document.getElementById("pw");
    if (un.value == "" || pw.value == "") {
        return false;
    }
};
```